# Restoring a fresh home folder in a shared user domain environment

Tags: windows, active-directory

I am using a tool called pGINA that adds another credential provider to my Windows 7 clients so we can authenticate campus users via campus LDAP. We have the default Windows credential providers setup to authenticate off of our Active Directory, but we have students in our classes that don't have entries in our AD, and we need to know who they are to allow them internet access. Once these LDAP users login using pGINA, they are all redirected to the same AD account, a 'kiosk' account with GPOs in place to prevent anything malicious. My concern is that my users will accidentally save personal login information or files in that shared profile, and another user may login later and have access to a previous user's Gmail account, as the AppData folder on each computer is shared by anyone logging into the kiosk user. I've looked into MS's 'roll-your-own' SteadyState but it didn't seem to have what I wanted. I tried to write a PS script to copy a pre-saved clean version of the profile from a network share, but I just kept running into issues with CredSSP delegation and accessing the share from the UNC path. Others have recommended something like DeepFreeze but I'd like to do it without 3rd party tools if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is a [Mandatory User Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776895.aspx).

> A mandatory user profile is a special type of pre-configured roaming user profile that administrators can use to specify settings for users. With mandatory user profiles, a user can modify his or her desktop, but the changes are not saved when the user logs off. The next time the user logs on, the mandatory user profile created by the administrator is downloaded.

Also from the previous link, [Creating a Mandatory User Profile](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg241183%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: It looks like it may work, but we are using Folder Redirection exclusively. I'll keep digging, thanks.